# Which reason does the system display for closed questions when users disagree?

Tags: support, close-reasons

If 5 users vote to close a question, it gets into the "on-hold" state. The system adds a footnote to the question:

> put on hold as off-topic by [... list of users ...]
>
> The reason for closing the question is listed here

What happens if the users choose different close reasons? Only one reason appears on the generated message. How does the system choose which reason gets displayed? Is it chosen randomly?

I always thought it would be some majority reason, but I have just seen a counterexample (I was the 5th user to vote for close; the votes split 2/3, and the system displays the minority reason).

Comment: MSE dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32700/what-happens-if-a-fifth-person-chooses-a-different-reason-to-close

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a couple different ways those messages are constructed.

For the top-level close reasons (off-topic, too broad, unclear, duplicate, opinion-based), the reason chosen is whichever reason had the most votes. In the case of a tie, it chooses the most recent vote that was one of those choices to break the tie.

Now, there are off-topic sub-reasons. Any sub-reason which gets at least 2 votes is always shown regardless of which one is chosen as "final" because the off-topic reason can list multiple sub-reasons. Due to the number of close votes, that means two different sub-reasons could be displayed. However, **custom off-topic reasons are not allowed to appear in the close notice box**. They will remain as a comment. If no other sub-reason receives at least 2 votes, then only the base off-topic message will be displayed.

Of course, a moderator close vote overrides both of these situations (overrides the close reason and their chosen off-topic reason only needs the 1 vote instead of 2).

---

In your particular case, all five users chose the off-topic top level reason, so the question was obviously closed as off-topic. Three of you chose a custom reason which cannot ever be displayed in the notice, and two selected a provided reason so it got displayed in the notice. It's nothing to do with the system choosing the minority. If the three of you had simply selected a different provided sub-reason, then both would have appeared in the box.